# SwiftyJSON - issues with parsing

Tags: ios, swift, swifty-json

I try to parse json with SwiftyJSON. One of the fields have url to image and i try to save it as NSData but I face crash and console errors. Crash appears when compiler comes to object creation

code it the following

```
var JSONStorage : [Article?]?
var objects = [Article?]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let number = arc4random_uniform(1000)
    let urlString = "http://wirehead.ru/article.json?\(number)"

    if let url = NSURL(string: urlString) {
        if let data = try? NSData(contentsOfURL: url, options: []) {
            let json = JSON(data: data)

            for element in json["article"].arrayValue {

                let id = Int(element["id"].stringValue)
                let title = element["title"].stringValue
                let subtitle = element["subtitle"].stringValue
                let body = element["body"].stringValue
                let img = element["images"]["main"].rawValue
                let obj:Article = Article(id: id!, title: title, subtitle: subtitle, body: body, mainImage: img as! NSData)

                objects.append(obj)
                print("We are inside if let")

            }

        }
    }

    print(objects)

}
```

Link to JSON is http://wirehead.ru/article.json and here is with highlight http://pastebin.com/AAEFjsQN

Error that I get is

[image]

Any advice ?

Comment: img is not NSData ...it is String...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`["images"]["main"]` contains an URL represented by a `String`

To get the image data, use something like this

```
let imgURLString = element["images"]["main"].stringValue
if let url = NSURL(string:imgURLString) {
  let img = NSData(contentsOfURL:url)
}
```